# I have a problem in this integration and would love some help on integration rules

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I have an equation (momentum equation) that I need to integrate over time and space. The issue is that I am not sure if my math is correct or not. I have questions about the integration of $\frac{d}{dx}(\dot m \cdot u)$ as I do understand that is needs some kind of special rule. Unfortunately I couldn't find it online and I couldn't remember it by myself. if anyone can help with this I will appreciate it. I also would like someone to check the rest of the equation after integration.

The original form of the equation is
\begin{gather*}
\frac{1}{A} \frac{d\dot m}{dt}+
\frac{1}{A} \frac{d}{dx}(\dot m \cdot u) + \frac{dP}{dx} +\frac{2 \cdot f \cdot \lvert u\rvert }{d_h \cdot A} \dot m  - \rho \cdot  g = 0 \\
\end{gather*}
The integration like this:
\begin{aligned}
\frac{1}{A}&\int_{x_{i-\frac{1}{2}}}^{x_{i+\frac{1}{2}}}  \int_{t_{n}}^{t_{n+1}} \frac{d\dot m}{dt}\,dt dx +
\frac{1}{A}\int_{t_{n}}^{t_{n+1}}\int_{x_{i-\frac{1}{2}}}^{x_{i+\frac{1}{2}}} \frac{d}{dx}(\dot m \cdot u)\,dx dt \\
+{} &\int_{t_{n}}^{t_{n+1}}\int_{x_{i-\frac{1}{2}}}^{x_{i+\frac{1}{2}}} \frac{dP}{dx}\,dx dt + \int_{t_{n}}^{t_{n+1}}\int_{x_{i-\frac{1}{2}}}^{x_{i+\frac{1}{2}}} \frac{2 \cdot f \cdot |u| }{d_h \cdot A} \dot m \,dx dt \\
-{} & \int_{t_{n}}^{t_{n+1}}\int_{x_{i-\frac{1}{2}}}^{x_{i+\frac{1}{2}}} \rho \cdot  g \,dx dt = 0.
\end{aligned}

I assume that the $\frac{1}{A}$, $\frac{2 \cdot f  }{d_h \cdot A}$, and $g$ value are constant value and the rest are unknown value variables.

For $\frac{1}{A} \int_{x_{i-\frac{1}{2}}}^{x_{i+\frac{1}{2}}}  \int_{t_{n}}^{t_{n+1}} \frac{d\dot m}{dt}\,dt dx = 0$ I think that $\frac{\Delta x}{A}(\dot m^{t_{n+1}}  _{i+\frac{1}{2}}-\dot m^{{t_{n}}} _{i+\frac{1}{2}})$ but I am not sure as I think that I should be using $ {i+\frac{1}{2}}$ and $ {i-\frac{1}{2}}$ but that is why I need help.

For $\int_{t_{n}}^{t_{n+1}}\int_{x_{i-\frac{1}{2}}}^{x_{I+\frac{1}{2}}} \rho \cdot  g \,dx dt = 0 $ I think that it will be  $\frac{\Delta x \Delta t}{A}(\rho^{t_{n+1}}-\rho^{t_{n+1}})$ and I am not sure if I should use $ {i+\frac{1}{2}}$ and $ {i-\frac{1}{2}}$ or just one of them or what.